# Tab's full tile is not displaying in Tablayout in android

Tags: java, android

```js
public class CustomerSameday extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String POSITION = "POSITION";
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private TabLayout mTabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer_sameday);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Sameday");

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        setupTabLayout(mTabLayout);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.demo, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void setupTabLayout(TabLayout tabLayout) {
        tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(POSITION, mTabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(savedInstanceState.getInt(POSITION));
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return new CDemoFragment();
            }
            else if (position == 1) {
                return new CDemo1Fragment();
            }
            else if (position == 2) {
                return new CDemo2Fragment();
            }
            else if (position == 3) {
                return new CDemo3Fragment();
            }
            else if (position == 4) {
                return new CDemo4Fragment();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_cdemo1);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_cdemo2);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.title_cdemo3);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.title_cdemo4);
                case 4:
                    return getString(R.string.title_cdemo5);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static class CDemoFragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cdemo, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public static class CDemo1Fragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cdemo1, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class CDemo2Fragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cdemo2, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class CDemo3Fragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cdemo3, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
    public static class CDemo4Fragment extends Fragment {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cdemo4, container, false);

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Above is layout file for creating Tabs.Tab's Title are not full displaying in Tabs.Below is the java file consisting of Adapter class and Fragment class.Title's name are not showing full.
I shared the image of layout .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9Onu.png)

Answer (score 0):

since you have five tab , you have to decrease the font size of title.

```
public void changeTabsFont(TabLayout tabLayout, Typeface typeface) {

        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(typeface);
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setAllCaps(false);
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can also change the font of title by above method.